# "Project exited with code 1" - docker first time launch

Tags: node.js, docker

Im trying to use docker to launch a project, however on first time use of `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

```
> @ start /app
> if test "$NODE_ENV" = "production"; then node build/server.js ; else babel-node tools/run start; fi

sh: 1: babel-node: not found
```

I have looked for a solution on other sites but am yet to find something that works or shows exactly what I'm getting or similar..I am quite new to this so any input/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have an error: "babel-node not found" Did you install all requirements?

Comment: Hi there, I had a colleague come over and install it but it still doesn't seem to work fully, I'm not sure if maybe something was left out etc

Comment: I've edited your question to replace the very large terminal screenshot with the text of the actual error you're getting.  Knowing a little bit more about your environment, and removing unnecessary details, will help people understand what you're asking; SO has some suggestions on writing a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidMaze apologies for this, many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally have an answer to this, turns out the docker sever had no way of detecting babel so a simple change in my `package.json` file did the trick, despite being somewhat lazy:

```
"start": "npm install; if test \"$NODE_ENV\" = \"production\"; then node build/server.js ; else babel-node tools/run start; fi"
```